# How can I sum parts of pytorch tensor of variable sizes?

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's consider example.
I have a tensor of size (10, 3).
I want to sum first 3 rows, next 2 rows and 5 next rows by 0 axis.
For example from:

```
t = torch.ones([10, 3])
```

I want to get:

```
[
    [3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
    [2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    [5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
]
```

I want to specify a tensor with values and a tensor with part sizes and possibly axis and get a tensor summed along this axis by parts of specified sizes.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Following the great idea of @ben-grossmann I modified it a little to use sparse tensor and make it more efficient. And implemented it as a function:

```
def sum_var_parts(t, lens):
    t_size_0 = t.size(0)
    ind_x = torch.repeat_interleave(torch.arange(lens.size(0)), lens)
    indices = torch.cat(
        [
            torch.unsqueeze(ind_x, dim=0),
            torch.unsqueeze(torch.arange(t_size_0), dim=0)
        ],
        dim=0
    )
    M = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(
        indices,
        torch.ones(t_size_0, dtype=torch.float32),
        size=[lens.size(0), t_size_0]
    )
    return M @ t
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-looping* approach is:

1. break tensor into subtensors based on splitting list
2. Pad (with 0s) and stack subtensors along a new dimension
3. Sum stack along desired dimension

The asterisk is because we can do the pad and stack with `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`. This function is implemented for quick computation making use of C-style threading for parallelized computation, which is likely much quicker than a `for` loop (though it's possible the C implementation of this function actually does use some looping). The one downside to this approach is that you very temporarily need to allocate memory for the padding zeros, so if the largest and smallest chunk sizes are vastly different this could cause a memory issue.

Ok, that's the explanation, here's the code:

```
def chunk_sum(X,chunk_lengths,dim = 0):
    # X has size [A,B,C...]
    # The sum of chunk_lengths must equal X.shape[dim]

    # X_chunk is a list of tensors of size [*varies*,B,C...] if dim=0, and so on
    X_chunk = torch.split.split(X,chunk_lengths,dim = dim)

    # X_chunk_pad is size [len(chunk_lengths),max(chunk_lengths),B,C,...] if dim=0 and so on
    X_chunk_pad = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(X_chunk,batch_first = True)
    # X_sum is size[len(chunk_lengths),B,C,...]
    X_sum = X_chunk_pad.sum(dim = 1+dim) # add one because we added batch dimension first


    # lastly, we need to permute dimensions so that batch (currently dimension 0) replaces dim
    X_sum = torch.transpose(X_sum,0,dim)

    return X_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use matrix multiplication. For example, consider the following.

```
import torch

lens = [3,2,5]
t = torch.ones([10, 3])

m,_ = t.size()
M = torch.zeros([len(lens),m])
ind_x = [i for i,L in enumerate(lens) for _ in range(L)]
M[ind_x,range(m)] = 1
ans = M@t
```

The resulting tensor `ans`:

```
tensor([[3., 3., 3.],
        [2., 2., 2.],
        [5., 5., 5.]])
```

---

Another approach:

```
lens = [2,3,5]
t = torch.ones([10, 3])

lens = torch.cumsum(torch.tensor([0]+lens),dim=0)
ans = torch.stack([torch.sum(t[a:b],axis = 0) for a,b in zip(lens,lens[1:])])
```

Comment: But what if I have (1000000, 100) tensor and parts of 10 average size. Then overhead will be huge 100000.

Comment: I think this should still be reasonably efficient. It's hard to think of an alternative that doesn't have some kind of for loop, at least over the parts

Comment: @Stepochkin I've added an alternative approach, perhaps this would be more efficient. It certainly uses less memory.